# I want to replace a certain column of a file with a list - Python

Tags: python

I have a stock file which looks like this:

```
12334232:seat belt:2.30:12:10:30
14312332:toy card:3.40:52:10:30
12512312:xbox one:5.30:23:10:30
12543243:laptop:1.34:14:10:30
65478263:banana:1.23:23:10:30
27364729:apple:4.23:42:10:30
28912382:orange:1.12:16:10:30
12892829:elephant:6.45:14:10:30
```

I want to replace the items in the fourth column if they are below the numbers in the fifth column after a certain transaction to the numbers in the sxith column. How would I replace the items in the fourth column?
Everytime I use the following lines of code below, it overwrites the whole file with nothing (deletes everything)

```
for line in stockfile:
     c=line.split(":")
     print("pass")
      if stock_order[i] == User_list[i][0]:
        stockfile.write(line.replace(current_stocklevel_list[i], reorder_order[i] ) )
     else:
         i = i + 1
```

I want the stockfile to look like this after it has replaced the necessary items in the column:

```
12334232:seat belt:2.30:30:10:30
14312332:toy card:3.40:30:10:30
12512312:xbox one:5.30:30:10:30
12543243:laptop:1.34:30::10:30
65478263:banana:1.23:30:10:30
27364729:apple:4.23:30:10:30
28912382:orange:1.12:30:10:30
12892829:elephant:6.45:30:10:30
```

Comment: you're using the same file for read and write. You cannot do that. And the rest of your code is wrong too.

Comment: In your else case you need to write out the unchanged line. Also it's not clear whether you're opening things in the right order; `w` mode truncates the file content.

Comment: What should I use in order to read and write, because in order to replace items in my file I should be able to read and write

Comment: 1. Read in whole file in `r` mode. 2. Reopen file in `w` mode to clear previous content and allow writing. 3. Iterate over data from 1 and write it back into file from 2.

Comment: Thanks,but I only want to write over a specific column

Comment: You cannot *"write over a specific column"* unless the new entry happens to be exactly the same number of bytes everywhere you're replacing it. The concept of lines and columns doesn't exist in a text file format.

Comment: So there in't a way to overwrite a specific line?:

Comment: Again, not unless it is exactly the same number of bits. That's why, as above, the easiest way is to read in all of the file, modify the content, then write it all back out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening file after some time, you should use "a" (append) as a mode so that file doesn't get truncated.

Write pointer will automatically be on the end of file.

So:

```
f = open("filename", "a")
f.seek(0) # To start from beginning
```

But if you want to read and write, then add "+" to the mode and file wouldn't be truncated as well.

```
f = open("filename", "r+")
```

Both read and write pointers will be at the beginning of file, you'll need to seek only onto position where you wish to start writing/reading.

But you are doing it wrong.

See, file's content will be overwritten, not inserted automatically.

If you are in writable mode and at the end of file content will be added.

So, you either need to load whole file, make changes you need and write everything back.

Or, you have to write changes at some point and shift remaining content truncating the file if the content is shorter than before.

mmap module can help you to treat file as a string,. You will be able to efficiently shift data and to resize the file.

But, if you really want to change file in place, you should have the file with fixed length of columns. So, when you want to change a value, you do not need to shift anything back and forth. Just find the right row and col, seek there, write new value over the old one (making sure to delete all of the old) and that is just that.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read in the data first:

```
with open('inputfile', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
```

Then you can loop over the data and edit as needed and write it out:

```
with open('outputfile', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        c = line.split(":")
        if random.randint(1,3) == 1:
            # update fourth column based on some good reason
            c[3] += 2
        outfile.write(':'.join(c) + '\n')
```

Or you could do it on go with something like:

```
with open('inputfile', 'r') as infile, open('outputfile', 'w') as outfile:
    line = infile.readline()
    c = line.split(":")
    if random.randint(1,3) == 1:
        # update fourth column based on some good reason
        c[3] += 2
    outfile.write(':'.join(c) + '\n')

os.rename('outputfile', 'inputfile')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: When I entered the code on python, it did not work for me

Comment: I don't know what would be worst. Shifting all the content after changed bytes or your on go solution. Imagine what happens if the file is 100 MB. You simply kill IO by writing down line by line, and on the other side, reading in same manner. And then you would have 2 files of 100 MB, then you would have to delete one of them. Blah-blah. Don't kill the OS for nothing. And users would probably murder you for waiting the operation to finish.

Comment: Let's hope that if the OP is storing 100MB of data it is not stored in this format.